# Flyway in common library that has integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I'm running into a silly situation where I have my flyway dependency defined in a common library's pom file.  This common library happens to have Spring Boot integration tests that load the context and so when those integration tests run I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)

I'd rather not duplicate the dependency definition in all of the applications' poms and I can't remove the integration tests.  I'd also rather not have a dummy migrations folder.  Can I just turn this off somehow in the integration tests?

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DisableFlywaySomehow
public class MyITest {...}
```

Comment: Use a different `profile` and just set `spring.flyway.enabled = false`, for that profile, in your `application.{properties,yml}` file. You can also try the same with the `test` profile you are using for the artifact in question...cheers!

Comment: The real question is: why are your integration tests co-located with your flyway migration? Why are they not in separate (sub-)modules?

Comment: Wait..  are you suggesting that flyway migrations should have their own module or that integration tests don't belong in a common library?  The latter I agree with.  The former would be news to me.

Comment: @x80486 thank you.  I knew I was missing something easy.  Go ahead and make that an answer if you want.

Comment: How about excluding the specific dependency?

Comment: That sort of Jiu-Jitsu is what makes thing worst on the long run. The problem is elsewhere, you just don't want to create another one by hacking this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different `profile` (although you can also use your current `test` profile) and just set `spring.flyway.enabled = false` in your `application.{properties,yml}` file.

You can also play with the `@TestPropertySource` annotation on a test-by-test case.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, your integration tests should operate on whatever state your app is "current". Which also means (if applicable) database. Why not incorporate `testcontainers` or similar tool to mimic real-life situation then it'll run actual migrations from source code and you'll test what's necessary.

The disabling of db sounds dodgy unless you are testing integrity of your application disregarding the database. In that case, provide `FlywayMigrationStrategy` as `null` - it will stop from executing any migrations and you'll have no DB environment.

Once again - it's up to your application